# Upgrade from .asmx to WCF in razor

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, razor

So I have been calling a method from a c# class from Razor using a .asmx file, and I have learned that .asmx is deprecated. I'm trying to figure out what to replace this method with. Here's what I'm doing now:

The C# program (GetConstantContactData.cs) looks like this:

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;




/// <summary>
/// Summary description for GetConstantContactData
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "https://[myurl].org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class GetConstantContactData : System.Web.Services.WebService {


 public string GetResponse()
    {
      //Get data from Constant Contact and return it as a JSON string
    }
```

The .asmx file (GetConstantContactData.asmx) looks like this:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/GetConstantContactData.cs" Class="GetConstantContactData" %>
```

And the Javascript ajax calls the .asmx file like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "../GetConstantContactData.asmx/GetResponse",
data: "{}",
success: SucceededCallback,
error: FailedCallback,
dataType: "json"
})
// Callback function that
// processes the service return value.
function SucceededCallback(result) {
     //do stuff with the data
}
```

It works now, but as I said I know this method is deprecated, and doesn't work in .NET 4. As I understand it I want to do this through WCF using a ServiceHost. I see how to do this using a ScriptManager [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924552(v=vs.110).aspx), but I want to know how to do it using Razor.

I've been searching the web for any kind of tutorial or guide on this. Just a link to the correct place to tell me how to do this would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Are you adding a service file to your existing asp.net web service or are you creating a WCF project? I would just keep it if it currently works with the old asmx

Comment: I want to keep it, but I need to switch to .NET version 4, which doesn't include WebService.

Comment: WCF is going to have a little bit of a learning curve. Is your web site and web service combined? I'd definitely have them as two individual projects. Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues with running an ASMX service in .Net 4. I currently have several running in production right now. The old ASMX services are 'deprecated' in favour of WCF, but they are not gone entirely. As @Anonymous suggests; don't fix it if it ain't broke. If you absolutely have to replace it, look at a WebAPI endpoint, that will probably be the simplest for what you need.

Comment: Anonymous, thanks for that link, that might help.

Comment: Brent, thanks for your comments. However when I tried to update to System.Net.Http version 4.0, I got the notification that the Webservice object no longer exists. This was when I realized that ASMX was deprecated. How does one use ASMX without Webservice?

Comment: Also, where is a good place to look for documentation on WebAPI endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Brent Mannering's suggestion of the WebAPI endpoint above was the best answer to this problem. It doesn't use WCF, but the Web API is a more useful lightweight solution to this problem that matches with what I was originally doing with the .asmx Webservice framework, and which is not deprecated.